# calculate time complexity of recursive algorithm

Tags: time-complexity

I wonder if someone can help me to find the time complexity ( Big O ()) of the following algorithm:( the algorithm is searching for a clique with the given size

```
Procedure CliqueFinder(C,ne,MaxCliqueSize)
For each u∈ne
    If ( (|n(u)| < MaxCliqueSize-|c|)  or  (|c|= MaxCliqueSize) )
        Break;
    Set n''(u) = (n'(u) ∩ ne)  drive from N'
    If (|n''(u) | >= MaxCliqueSize-|c|-1)
        Set c = c∪{u}
    CliqueFinder (c,n''(u),MaxCliqueSize);
    Remove u from ne
    If (|c|= MaxCliqueSize)
      Return c;
```

Comment: you need to make the pseudocode clearer or better yet post real code. What is "ne"? What is "n(u)"? what does " Set n''(u) = (n'(u) ∩ ne)  drive from N' " mean? etc.